# error in passing parameters to php file using ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, curl, urlencode

I am doing a project which records video from Ip camera . I used ajax to run my program back end which successfully records video using code from process.php file. However i am trying to make program more dynamic for each user and I am facing problem passing parameters to my next page i.e record.php
the 2 parameters i want to pass are email & url i tried the following way to pass variables to my process.php using ajax link   :

```
xmlhttp.open('GET','http://localhost/IPCAM/process.php?sh=1&url=<?php echo $url ?>&email=<?php echo $email ?>',true);
```

Here is the complete script.
Can anyone suggest me proper way to write the above url to work dynamically.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function st()
{
                        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
                        {
                            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
                        }
                        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
                        {
                            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                            {
                            alert('stored');
                            }

                        }
                        xmlhttp.open('GET','http://localhost/IPCAM/process.php?sh=1&url=<?php echo $url ?>&email=<?php echo $email ?>',true);
                        xmlhttp.send();

setTimeout('st()',5000);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try URL encoding your php vars like:

```
xmlhttp.open('GET','http://localhost/IPCAM/process.php?sh=1&url=<?php echo urlencode($url) ?>&email=<?php echo urlencode($email); ?>',true);
```

I have used pattern before. This assumes that the page containing the JavaScript like the above code is actually a .php file having. Although a better way to design your application would be to include javascript as an external file in that case you should do something like:

```
$export_vars = array('url' => $url, 'email' => $email);
echo '<script type="text/javascript">' .
    'var userData = ' . json_encode($export_vars) . ";" .
    '</script>';
```

while your initial javascript function must be rewritten as:

```
function st(url, email)
```

Comment: thanks but does this statement works if i use it in my script? 
because i think you cannot directly refer php variables in scrpit.
is there any way how i can make  xmlhttp.open to accept an use php parameters i pass

Comment: @RogerMendes Reply in-answer.